# How can I determine if the player holds the top leaderboard spot in Game Center?

Tags: game-center

I have integrated Game Center into my game and I want to make an achievement that is earned if the user holds the #1 spot on Game Center.

How do I access that information with code?

Comment: How are you able to implement something into your game and not know what forums are...https://developer.apple.com/game-center/ There should be a forum link there somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. @Sidar This is my first game, I am 13, and I have been using Cocos2d for my first game. Cocos2d has a great community and I have used their forums and its the only one I have needed to use. Now that I have explored and found out about the forums it will replace the Cocos2d forums.

Comment: @PoKoBros You don't replace the forum. Apple Game Center and Cocos2d are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [the `GKLeaderboard` API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboard_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKLeaderboard). As described in the documentation for [recovering score data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW32), you want to use the leaderboard object to represent a query to the Game Center service for leaderboard information, specifically setting the range to `[1, 1]` to return only the top score. This code would look something like this:

```
GKLeaderboard * request = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
request.range = NSMakeRange(1, 1);
[request loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray * scores, NSError * error) { 
   // Handle the error or process the scores.
}];
```

The `scores` array contains `GKScore` objects, which have a player ID field you can use to compare against the current player's ID to determine if they are the player holding the top score or not.